# What is the difference between "infrastructure as a service" (IaaS) and "private cloud"

Tags: cloud-hosting, cloud

Despite searching Google and reading articles, I have been unable to figure out the difference between Infrastructure as a service and Private Cloud. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

"Infrastructure as a Service" is usually delivered on a shared platform, for example renting Virtual Machines and networking on Azure/AWS etc. or even from a traditional hosting provider.

"Private Cloud" typically means you have your own "cloud like" setup hosted on dedicated hardware. With the likes of Azure Pack and OpenStack these environments can be very similar to the experience of using the public cloud in terms of management experience and options.

With IaaS you don't really have to worry about capacity as that is taken care of by the provider, so if you require another VM, or need more memory/compute on your instances you can usually scale as needed, however with Private Cloud if your hardware is fully allocated and you need another VM you may have some issues.